# Creating makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, configure

I am trying to create the makefiles and configure for my library which its directory structure is like following:

```
 $projectroot
    ├── lib
    ├── src
    └── test
```

this library has 3 different parts (part1, part2 and part3) and it is a hierarchal library, that means part2 needs part1, part 3 needs part2 and part1:

```
 part1 ◁───┐
    △      │
    │      │
   part2   │
      △    │
      │    │
      │    │
     part3 ┘
```

Now, I want to have 4 different targets, as you can see below:

```
all:
       <MAKE ALL THE 3 PARTS>

part1:      
       <MAKE PART1>

part2:
       <MAKE PART2>

part3:
       <MAKE PART3>
```

I have no problem with make (make all), but for example maybe someone wants only to install  part2, I need to verify whether part2 is already installed or not

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need to "verify whether part2 is already installed or not"? I think you may be mixing installation and build here. If you want to parallelize your builds more, check out: http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/ ...

Comment: I agree. as in this duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6175802/848072 one thing is build, and another install and there you have the answer. Normally make doesn't check installed libs, but you can create a target and use `locate` or something like this http://serverfault.com/a/54739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just list `part1` and `part2` as dependencies of `part3`:

```
all: part1 part2 part3

part1:
   MAKE PART1

part2: part1
   MAKE PART2

part3: part1 part2
   MAKE PART3
```