# creating makefile

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, configure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174029/creating-makefile)

Hello, I am trying to create the makefiles and configure for my library which its directory structure is like following:

```
 $projectroot
    ├── part1
    │   ├── src
    │   └── lib
    ├── part2
    │   ├── src
    │   └── lib
    └── part3
        ├── src
        └── lib
```

As you can see, this project has 3 different parts, Someone would want to install the entire project, or someone might need only one library from project.

I have a Makefile like the following:

```
SUBDIRS = part1/lib part1/src part2/lib part2/src part3/lib part3/src

part1:
    cd part1/lib; make
    cd part1/src; make

part2:
    cd part2/lib; make
    cd part2/src; make

part3:
    cd part3/lib; make
    cd part3/src; make
```

The problem comes around when I use

```
$ make part1 install
```

that installs the whole project but I want just to install part1, not all the parts

How can I do that?

Comment: Please stop repeating your question. It will only get closed, and you may get banned.

Comment: Actually each times, it is new problem , but with the same title

Comment: Please, in [your initial question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174029/creating-makefile), comment on why the answer given is not sufficient and edit the question to add the new requirements instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really difficult to parse, but I have a feeling that you need an additional set of install targets for each part:

```
part1_install: part1
  cd part1/lib; make install
  cd part1/src; make install
```

Then you can just execute `make part1_install` (part1 will be built implicitly).